# Opening spyder in Windows subsystem for Linux fails

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu, spyder, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed `spyder` through the `Windows Subsystem for Linux` system and am having problems opening the program from the command line (command line of `Bash on Ubuntu on Windows` application on Windows)

```
spyder
```

error given:

```
Spyder: cannot connect to X server
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm also having this issue, but with Kile.

Answer (score 0):

"cannot connect to X server" means you don't have running an x server. You can download one here https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/

After installing and running VcxSrv then you can type on bash      `DISPLAY=:0 spyder`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. It loads Spyder but then it all freezes with the following message in the bash terminal: user@computername:~$ DISPLAY=:0 spyder
QInotifyFileSystemWatcherEngine::addPaths: inotify_add_watch failed: Invalid argument
QFileSystemWatcher: failed to add paths: /home/mplain
OMP: Error #100: Fatal system error detected.
OMP: System error #22: Invalid argument

Comment: Inotify and file watchers are not implemented yet. They are already working on it and soon will be available for testing on the Windows Insider builds. https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/13469097-support-for-filesystem-watchers-like-inotify

Comment: Seems to be a problem with OpenMP (OMP error). Try to `export KMP_AFFINITY=disabled` (see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302683/omp-error-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows and https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/785)